# Omit meta-data from oData response

Tags: wcf, jsonp, odata

I'm experimenting with writing Javascript/JSONP queries against an WCF oData API. For performance reasons, I'm trying to keep the responses succinct. The default seems to be for the oData endpoint to return uri and type metadata with every returned result. This information can take up a significant portion of response payload. Is there a way to ask the oData endpoint to omit this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there's no way in the OData protocol to achieve that. Technically the metadata is part of the response, that's what makes it OData and not just arbitrary JSON.